# header file (.h) creation in c programming

Tags: c, eclipse

I am new to eclipse, developing c program in eclipse

I am creating multiple source files in same project, could some one help me to create .h file for main () function and to call in multiple source file

for instance if I have created main.c file, now how to call this main.c into another .c file

Answer (score 5):

The `main()` function should not be in a header file. It should be in one and only one `.c` file.

An example of simple layout can be:

**//header.h**

```
#ifndef MY_HEADER <----Notice the Inclusion Guards, read more about them in a good book
#define MY_HEADER

void doSomething();

#endif //MY_HEADER
```

**//header.c**

```
#include "header.h"

void doSomething()
{


}
```

**//Main.c**

```
#include "header.h"

int main(void)
{
    doSomething();
    return 0;
}
```

But please pick up a **[good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)** to learn these basics, You definitely need one.

Comment: Could you kindly suggest one for me

Comment: Why are you using ".cpp" for a question on C?

Comment: @unwind: I answer mostly on C++, and that was a typo, It should be `.c`, not that it makes any difference here.

Comment: @Chaithu: Please check the link I have added to the answer, It has books grouped for all levels of competency.Pick up any beginner level book in the list there, It should be good for you.